# inserting to mysql database Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' and Duplicate entry '1' for key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to insert data in mysql database.
i inserted only one property in mysql database and than code stop because of conflict with unique id and transactionManager .
Here is the error message

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader [main] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [springmvc/java/config/ApplicationContext.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [test-data.sql]: INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES('admin','password',TRUE); nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user.UK_6bcfe04eb95e4180b3873f8c09d'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4676) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1830) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.38.B.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.38.B.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.38.B.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.38.B.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [test-data.sql]: INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES('admin','password',TRUE); nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user.UK_6bcfe04eb95e4180b3873f8c09d'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [test-data.sql]: INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES('admin','password',TRUE); nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user.UK_6bcfe04eb95e4180b3873f8c09d'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:486) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:229) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext.transactionManager(ApplicationContext.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26d2e1ff.CGLIB$transactionManager$4(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26d2e1ff$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c52653d7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26d2e1ff.transactionManager(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user.UK_6bcfe04eb95e4180b3873f8c09d'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:472) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

my application-context.java configuration for mysql connection

```
@Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), dataSource());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("springmvc.java.domain");
        
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
    
    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(false);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("test-data.sql"));
        return databasePopulator;
    }
```

my entities configuration
User and blog post table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="username", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name="password", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name="enabled", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private boolean enabled;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<BlogPost> blogPosts;

 
@Entity
@Table(name="blog_post")
public class BlogPost {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) //tried IDENTITY
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="title", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name="content", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String content;
    
    @Column(name="publishDate", unique=true, nullable=true)
    private Date publishDate;
    
    @Column(name="draft", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private boolean draft;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;
```

and this is the environment property file which i want to insert

```
INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES('user','password',TRUE);
INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES('admin','password',TRUE);
INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES('test1@outlook.com','12345',TRUE);
INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES('test2@outlook.com','12345',TRUE);

INSERT INTO BLOG_POST (CONTENT,DRAFT,PUBLISHDATE,TITLE,USER_ID) VALUES('Test content MVC',false,NOW(),'test',1);
```

After exectution tables are created and first user and blog_post are inserted.

I really cannot find the solution.. relations seams to be oke, probably is something with transaction manager, but i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `unique = true` on every column? This will create unique constraints for the columns. As you can see in the exception message, a database unique constraint was violated and I bet it's because of `@Column(name="enabled", unique=true, nullable=false)`.

Just remove all the `unique = true` uses.